# Simplest way to provide memory, disk and CPU isolation without downloading images

Tags: cgroups

I am familiar with Docker, Rkt and LXD, but if I did not have the ability to install all these tools, what would be the basic mechanisms to provide isolation of CPU, memory and Disk for a particular process?

CPU - I want to say that only 1 socket of the two is usable by this process

Memory - I don't want this process to use more than 10GB memory

Disk - I don't want the process to use more than 100GB of disk and have visibility (ls should not list it) of files that are not created by this process

I think installing Docker, Rkt and what-not is very heavy weight solution for something basic that I am trying to accomplish

**Is cgroups the underlying API I should tap into to get what I need? If so, is there a good book to learn about CGroups**

I am running on EC2 - RHEL and Ubuntu both.

Answer (score 1):

See [man page for cgroups(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html) for introduction, the full documentation of cgroup interface is maintained in linux kernel:

- [cgroup v1](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt)
- [cgroup v2](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v2.txt)

On top of that, on a distribution with systemd and cgroup v2 interface, [cgroup features should be used via systemd and not directly](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/ControlGroupInterface/). See also man page for [systemd.resource-control](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html).

For distribution specific information, see:

- [RHEL 6 Resource Management Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/)
- [RHEL 7 Resource Management Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/resource_management_guide/)

### Quick answers to your questions

> I want to say that only 1 socket of the two is usable by this process

This could be done via cpuset controller from cgroup v1 (both on [RHEL 6](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/sec-cpuset) and [RHEL 7](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1445073)).

> I don't want this process to use more than 10GB memory

See memory controller of cgroup v1 interface or `MemoryLimit` of systemd resource control interface.

> I don't want the process to use more than 100GB of disk

This is out of cgroups area of control, use disk quotas instead.

> have visibility (ls should not list it) of files that are not created by this process

This is out of cgroups functionality, use either filesystem access right, filesystem namespaces or [PrivateTmp systemd service option](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#PrivateTmp=), depending on your use case.